# How to make tabs with webview to load from a web address?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-webview, android-tabs

I want to build an application in Android Studio. I have inside tabs:

```
| tab one | tab two | tab three |
```

...and each tab should load a webview page.

For example: tab one should load www.google.com, and tab two should load www.youtube.com, ...

How can I build this?

Comment: Welcome so SO ;-) What help do you need to build this exactly? Someone else to do it for you can't be found here. Please edit your question to show what you have and tried.

Comment: @StefanHegny I want build application in android studio There are inside tabs :tab one | tab two | tab three | . and each tap load webview page 
ex:tab one load www.google.com tab tow load www.youtube.con

Comment: I rephrased and formatted your question. Please add the code you have tried with.

Answer (score 1):

Here It Is

activity_main.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

MainActivity.java

```
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

// Declaring our tabs and the corresponding fragments.
ActionBar.Tab bmwTab, fordTab, toyotaTab;
Fragment bmwFragmentTab = new Fragment();
Fragment toyotaFragmentTab = new Fragment();
Fragment fordFragmentTab = new Fragment();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Asking for the default ActionBar element that our platform supports.
    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();

    // Screen handling while hiding ActionBar icon.
    actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);

    // Screen handling while hiding Actionbar title.
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

    // Creating ActionBar tabs.
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    // Setting custom tab icons.


    // Setting tab listeners.
    bmwTab.setTabListener((ActionBar.TabListener) new Fragment1());
    toyotaTab.setTabListener((ActionBar.TabListener) new Fragment2());
    fordTab.setTabListener((ActionBar.TabListener) new Fragment3());

    // Adding tabs to the ActionBar.
    actionBar.addTab(bmwTab);
    actionBar.addTab(toyotaTab);
    actionBar.addTab(fordTab);
}
}
```

PagerAdapter.java

```
import android.app.ActionBar.Tab;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.app.ActionBar;

public class PagerAdapter implements ActionBar.TabListener {

private Fragment fragment;

// The contructor.
public PagerAdapter (Fragment fragment) {
    this.fragment = fragment;
}

// When a tab is tapped, the FragmentTransaction replaces
// the content of our main layout with the specified fragment;
// that's why we declared an id for the main layout.
@Override
public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    ft.replace(R.id.activity_main, fragment);
}

// When a tab is unselected, we have to hide it from the user's view.
@Override
public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    ft.remove(fragment);
}

// Nothing special here. Fragments already did the job.
@Override
public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

}
}
```

activity_fragment1.xml

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.ss.tabswithwebview.Fragment1">

<WebView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/webView">

</WebView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Fragment1.java

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class Fragment1 extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_fragment1, container, false);
    WebView webView=(WebView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.webView);
    webView.loadUrl("www.google.com");
    return rootView;
}

}
```

Similarly create different fragment as created above.

Answer (score 0):

My codes

```
import android.app.ActionBar.Tab;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.app.ActionBar;

public class Adapter implements ActionBar.TabListener {

private android.support.v4.app.Fragment fragment;

// The contructor.
public Adapter(android.support.v4.app.Fragment fragment) {
this.fragment = fragment;
}

@Override
public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
ft.replace(R.id.activity_main, fragment);
}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
ft.remove(fragment);
}

@Override
public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

}
}
```

When a tab is tapped, the FragmentTransaction replaces the content of our main layout with the specified fragment; that's why we declared an id for the main layout.

Comment: İ receive error when i write import.android.app.Fragment

Comment: Should edit your Question to add the code instead of posting it in the Answer section. Please read this [how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score -1):

Actually FragmentActivites Need To Be Created 
and in Your layouts You neeed to SetBackground As Your Wish Color So That activity_main is not loaded Along With FragmentLayout

And for Webview 
Just Add Webview And Load Url In each fragments According to Yourself

Comment: thank you for answered me : you can create simple project  for it ???or give me link??